# White and black image to 2D array and after some operations 2D array to image in Java

Tags: java, arrays, image

I want to convert image to 2D array , do some operations on it and then once again convert changed 2D array to image. I spent a lot of time on searching solution but any of them was correct. There is no good answer for this problem in internet. Please tell me that I'am wrong.

Comment: Post the code you have, what you've tried, and how each of those tries failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
package game;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author rafal
 */
public class Game {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/rafal/Pulpit/obraz.png"));
        byte[][] pixels = new byte[image.getWidth()][];

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
    pixels[x] = new byte[image.getHeight()];

    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        pixels[x][y] = (byte) (image.getRGB(x, y) == 0xFFFFFFFF ? 0 : 1);
    }
}

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
         for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
         {
             if(pixels[x][y] == 1);
             pixels[x][y] = 0;
         }

    }
    /*
 * Create a new 1-dimensional byte array which will hold the result
 * Set its size to the item count in the pixelData array
 */
byte[] oneDimArray = new byte[pixels.length * pixels[0].length];
 byte[][] twoDimArray = new byte[ image.getWidth()][ image.getHeight()];
/*
 * Loop through the "horizontal" row in the pixelData array
 */
for(int x = 0; x < pixels.length; x++) {
    /*
     * Loop through each item in the current vertical row
     */
    for(int y = 0; y < pixels[x].length; y++) {

        /*
         * Set each item in the 1-dimensional array to the corresponding
         * item in the 2-dimensional array
         */
        oneDimArray[x + y * pixels.length] = twoDimArray[x][y];
    }
}

   ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(oneDimArray);
   BufferedImage finalImage = ImageIO.read(byteIn);

   ImageIO.write(finalImage, "png",new File("/home/rafal/Pulpit/obraz2.png"));


    }

}
```

I wanted to change all black pixels to white pixels. But generally method is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to make an array of your image first, you can just simply use `setRGB(x,y,rgb);` If you want your array `image.getRaster().getDataBuffer().getData()` will return you one.

Comment: But I need two dimensional array! Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: In nested for loops you can make it into a 2D array, once you have an array of pixels you can do whatever you want with them. Why is it important to have a 2D array?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            int pixel = image.getRGB(x,y);
            int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;

            // now you can access r g b values as 0-255 integers
            // you can do whatever you want with them 

            int outColor = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
            image.setRGB(x,y,outColor);  // this way you can set it back together

            your2dArray[x][y] = outColor; // you can also save each pixel in a 2D array
                                          // anytime

        }
    }
```

These are just a few techniques that helps you work with pixels, there are a lot of other ways you can do it, also these should be in different methods, its just a representation. I don't know why is it important to have your pixels in 2d array, but of course it can work.